# How can I display the result of a command with two decimals in powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

How can I display the following command with only two decimals:

```
dir F:\ -File -Recurse | where Extension | group Extension | select name, count,@{Name="Size";Expression={ (($_.group | measure length -sum).sum)/ 1024 }} | sort count -Descending
```

I know how to do it with {0:N2} -f $x in a script but not in a single command.

Comment: so why can't you use it here? i don't see any reason not to, `{0:N2} -f (($_.group | measure length -sum).sum) / 1024`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the type `math` with it's static method `round()`

```
dir F:\ -File -Recurse | where Extension | group Extension | select name, count,@{Name="Size";Expression={ [math]::round((($_.group | measure length -sum).sum)/ 1024 ,2) }} | sort count -Descending
```

Comment: Thank you @restless1987. Now I know